# Adding and Deleting nodes from linked list

Tags: c

2 Questions:

1. I'm writing a function to prepend a node to a list. Currently I have it like this:

   ```
   void addList( NODE_TYPE** head, NODE_TYPE** d_name )
   {
       (*d_name)->next = *head;
       *head = *d_name;
   }
   ```

   and inside `main()`, I call it like this:

   ```
   addList( &head, &node_3);
   ```

   My question is, is there another way to do this with a function prototype such as:

   ```
   void addList( NODE *head, NODE *node);
   ```

   ?

   This was a class problem, and I don't understand how prepending can be done with the above function prototype since calling the function would only pass in the value of the address, the caller would be unable to see any changes made to the head nor the node.
2. I'm unsure if my deleteList function is right. I want it so that the temp points to where head (anchor) points to. Then the next_free points to the 2nd node linked with the head. Then I free the first node. Then repeat for the second, third and so on, until all of them are freed.

   ```
   void deleteList( NODE_TYPE** head )
   {
       NODE_TYPE* temp = *head;
       NODE_TYPE* next_free = NULL;

       while ( temp->next != NULL )
       {
           next_free = temp->next;
           free( temp );
           temp = next_free;
       }

       *head = NULL;
   }
   ```

Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

To answer number 1, you can use what's called a *dummy head*.  That is an empty node whose `next` pointer points to the first element in your list.  So you create your empty list as a single node, and then pass that node around knowing that its pointer won't change.  This is useful if you intend to store pointers to the head of your list in multiple places but allow the list to change.

For number 2, it's almost right, but you want to make sure that `*head` is not NULL initially.  Also, it won't delete a list containing only one element.  Do this instead:

```
while ( temp != NULL )
```

And leave everything else the same.

Oh, another note about your first question.  You are wrong when you say this:

> calling the function would only pass in the value of the address, the
>   caller would be unable to see any changes made to the head **nor the
>   node**.

The contents of the node can change.  You don't need a double pointer to it.  The double pointer means the *pointer* can change.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid the extra "next_free" variable by directly assigning to *head:

```
void deleteList( NODE_TYPE **head )
{
    NODE_TYPE *temp;

    while ( (temp = *head) )
    {
        *head = temp->next;
        free( temp );
    }

}
```

Comment: This generally results in more instructions because the `head` pointer must be dereferenced each time.  I believe this would not be the case if the pointer was declared with the `restrict` keyword.  This is just a general point, but would not be significant here because calling `free` is a much lengthier operation.

Comment: Formally you are right, but I don't care about performance (the whole thing would be in cache anyway). Smaller code := {easyer reading, fewer chances for bugs}

Comment: I agree.  Was just nit-picking =)

Answer (score 0):

**"My question is, is there another way to do this with a function prototype such as:
void addList( NODE *head, NODE *node)"**

Well you are right. If you just "**pass by value**" the changes you reflect will not apply to the original subroutine. What you can do is this:

```
Node_type * addList(Node_type *head, Node_type *d_name)
{
d_name->next=head;
return d_name;
}
```

In the caller function call in this format

```
 head = addList( head, node_3);
```

This would reflect the change you want to see

**For Q2**

Just put the condition

**while(temp!=NULL)**

This would take care of the condition where there is an **empty list** or a list **with single node**